# How do I get css paragraph numbering to work in a scroll box?

Tags: css, numbers, paragraph

In order to solve an issue at work, I've been learning how to do paragraph numbering with css. So far, I am pleased with the results for standalone text passages. However, my requirement is to do the same in a scroll box with a vertical scrollbar.

As you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/Lceewqj3/3/, I have gotten close by removing absolute positioning from the paragraph numbers, and adding a right margin, but I am still having a problem getting the paragraph starting left edge to be positioned correctly. My solution must work correctly for double-digit paragraph numbers as well as single, so the fixed right margin doesn't work, as you can see by scrolling down to paragraph 10. I tried adding a width property, but that didn't work either.

Note that modifying the existing `passage-scrolling` style is something I am not at liberty to do, so I need a solution that involves only manipulating the `chapter` and/or `page` styles.

Here is the css for the fiddle:

```
  .chapter {
    counter-reset: paragraph;
    padding-left: 30px;
  }
  .page p {
    width: 75%;
  }
  .page p:before {
    //position: absolute;
    margin-left: -30px;
    margin-right: 14px;
    color: #000;
    font-style: italic;
    content: counter(paragraph);
    counter-increment: paragraph;
  }
  p {
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 22px;
    font-weight: 400;
  }
  .passage-scrolling {
    padding: 0 5%;
    height: 340px;
    width: 89%;
    border: 2px solid #999;
    overflow-y: auto;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone at work figured this out for me. The answer was simply to add `float:left;` and `text-align:left;` and remove the right margin from the `.page p:before` style. See the result here: http://jsfiddle.net/Lceewqj3/5/

Here's the final css that worked correctly:

```
  .chapter {
       counter-reset: paragraph;
       padding-left: 30px;
  }
  .page p {
       width: 75%;
  }
  .page p:before {
       float: left;
       text-align: left;
       margin-left: -30px;
       font-style: italic;
       content: counter(paragraph);
       counter-increment: paragraph;
  }
```

Comment: If anyone is still interested after reading this far, I have simplified it still further: jsfiddle.net/Lceewqj3/6 -- now all you have to do is add one <div class="auto-numbering"> encompassing all the <p>'s you want numbered.